# How to do a email verification to firebase user for signup and email update using FirebaseAuth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an android app for which I'm using Firebase Auth. In reference API we have a method sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) for resetting password. But I couldn't find any methods to send email verification for signup process and email change process. Even that reset password email contains one link which is expired when i open on the very first time itself. Does firebase have the solution for it?

Comment: @Shubhank Using FirebaseAuth is there any way to do email confirmation like that method that i mentioned in description??

Comment: you should read the doc for it. i believe there isnt one

Comment: There is no references in doc about using those mail templates except resetting password option :(